# Add a column with duplicated values based on other dataset - pandas (Add stock market index's data to each share by day.)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset (Panel data) of the Dow Jones' stocks with daily data (named 'data'):

```
      day_count    date     symbol   open     high      low    close  \
0              0 2013-05-31    AXP   76.13   77.385   75.710   75.710   
1              0 2013-05-31     BA  100.21  100.950   99.020   99.020   
...          ...        ...    ...     ...      ...      ...      ...   
14275        475 2014-09-18    UTX  107.41  108.660  107.410  108.520   
14276        475 2014-09-18      V  215.93  216.680  215.145  216.440
```

I have another dataset of the Dow Jones index's daily data (named 'djia'):
(Don't be worried about the missing observation as in indexes 1,2 - the first dataset contains them as well)

```
        date  DJ_Open  DJ_High   DJ_Low    Close DJ_Adj_Close  DJ_Volume
0  2013-05-31  15322.2  15392.4  15115.6  15115.6      15115.6  208830000
1  2013-06-01                                                            
2  2013-06-02                                                            
3  2013-06-03  15123.5  15254.1  15123.5    15254        15254  147980000
...
```

I want to prepare this dataset for regression, and so I want to add to each row of the first dataset these 5 columns from the second data set ('DJ_Open'...'DJ_Volume'), based on the date ('day_count' on the first dataset, the index in the second). However, when I tried this:

```
data['DJ_High'] = djia.loc[data.day_count, 'DJ_High']
```

I have got an error: 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'.

Can anybody introduce me with a neat solution, or give other useful comments on this purpose?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use merge:

```
df = df1.merge(df2[['dj_open'...'dj_volume']],on=['date','day_count'],how='left')
```

Comment: Thanks! I added 'day_count' to the second df then: 
data = pd.merge(data, djia, on=['day_count'],how='left') worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work.  You just want to use the pandas merge function.

```
new_df = data.merge(djia, on='date')
```